# merge sort using python, list index out of range

Tags: python, list, mergesort

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T77Jw.png)I am trying to sort a text file with content as follows:

afsdgf(name) 34(marks)

asdsad 45

erttre 56

....such 2000 records

### I am getting an IndexError as follows:

```
 if int(record_list[h][1]) >= int(record_list[j][1]):
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

### Here is the following code:

```
import sys


def merge_sort(low, high):
    if low < high:
        mid = int((low + high) / 2)
        merge_sort(low, mid)
        merge_sort(mid + 1, high)
        merge(low, mid, high)


def merge(low, mid, high):
    duplicate_list = []
    global record_list
    h = low
    j = mid + 1
    while h <= mid and j <= high:
        if int(record_list[h][1]) >= int(record_list[j][1]): #problem
            duplicate_list.append(record_list[h])
            h += 1
        else:
            duplicate_list.append(record_list[j])
            j += 1

    if h > mid:
        while j <= high:
            duplicate_list.append(record_list[j])
            j += 1
    else:
        while h <= mid:
            duplicate_list.append(record_list[h])
            h += 1

    record_list = duplicate_list.copy()


sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)


myFile = open("C:\TurboC++\Disk\TurboC3\BIN\sample.txt", encoding="utf-8", 
mode="r")
record_list = []

while True:
    line = myFile.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    record_list.append(line.split())
merge_sort(0, 500)

print(record_list)
```

I have just started using python, help.

Comment: At a guess, you probably need to change those `j <= high` to `j < high`.

Comment: Well, what are `h` and `j` at the point of error?  How many items do you have in the list?  Remember that the maximum list index is `len(record_list)-1`.

Comment: @Prune at the point of error `h=0` and `j=1`, and yeah I know about `len(record_list)-1`, just tried something different.